# Did Chipotle give away free burritos on Feb 8, 2016?

Tags: united-states, advertising

From [Chipotle's web-site](https://www.chipotle.com/raincheck), I can see they were giving away free burritos. This was apparently due to them being closed for staff meetings on February 8th.

Is it a real offer?

[image]

Comment: Snopes says it's legit: http://www.snopes.com/2016/02/08/free-chipotle-burrito-coupon/

Comment: "Message and data rates" almost always means "whatever your mobile carrier charges you for the text messages and/or mobile data that are involved here".  So the cost will depend on your particular carrier and contract.  For many people who have "unlimited" plans it will be $0.00.  But if you're on a plan where you pay, say, $0.10 to send or receive messages, this sentence is supposed to alert you that the messages involved in this offer are not exempt from that.

Comment: @NateEldredge oh ok, post it as an answer and I will check as correct!

Comment: Ive put this on hold - your question title does not match the text of the question. The question in the title is ok, the question in the body is not. The answer you've given does not answer the question in the title, so.... basically this is a mess. Fix it up, and flag if you want it re-opened.

Comment: @Jamiec I've edited the question so it's on topic and works with the highest answer. Do you think we can reopen now?

Comment: @Sklivvz yes, for sure. Now they match, and the question is (more-or-less) on-topic.

Answer (score 15):

Yes. [Time](http://time.com/4212129/chipotle-closed-free-burrito-raincheck/) confirmed this and wrote a story about it:

> All you have to do to redeem this offer is text the word “raincheck” to 888-222. They’ll text you back with a coupon for a **free burrito** within the next few days.

So did [Fox](http://fox2now.com/2016/02/08/heres-how-to-get-your-free-chipotle-burrito-raincheck/), [CBS](http://detroit.cbslocal.com/2016/02/08/chipotle-offers-free-burritos-to-win-back-customers-trust/) (who said "the text seemed to work"), and many others.

The page cited in the question linked to the [Offical Rules](https://www.chipotle.com/raincheck-giveaway) which clarifies about your phone charge concerns:

> NO PURCHASE OR PAYMENT OF ANY KIND IS NECESSARY TO PARTICIPATE.

There does not appear to be any hidden charges, beyond the normal fees required to operate a device that can send a text, receive an image and display a QR code.

Comment: Deleted a pointless, and borderline hostile, argument about whether incidental charges, like SMS and data charges, are included in the definition of "free". Accept you are using different definitions; move on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is entirely appropriate given the posting guidelines say "Avoid statements based solely on ... personal experience;", however, I don't think those were written with this specific situation in mind (also I cannot comment, as I do not have an account).

In case you hadn't guessed, I personally got a free burrito. I went there for lunch on Feb. 8th, 2016 at about 12:30pm and there was a sign on the door similar to the one in the question. I texted the number as directed, they sent me a link to their website where I was required to enter my name, phone number, and zip code.

The next day I received a text saying "Here it is. Ur free burrito." and a link to a site with a QR code. I went to chipotle the next day (wed. the 10th), showed the cashier the QR code on my phone, she scanned it, and I got a free burrito. To be perfectly clear, the only thing I got was a burrtio (with extra steak, even) and was not charged anything (ie. I did not give they my credit card or any money). I did not incur any texting fees as I have unlimited texting with my phone plan.

I'm not entirely sure why you are skeptical of this, considering the link you posted is from Chiptole's official site... Regardless, it is/was a legitimate offer.

And they say there is no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1505)! Please [provide some references](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to support your claims.